# Wss 3.0 Lookup field error "Field type Reminder is not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete this field. "

Tags: wss-3.0, custom-list

I tried to add lookup field in wss 3.0 custom list it errors saying"Field type Reminder is not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete this field. "

Has anyone ever encountered with this problem? IS there a quick fix for this problem.
[image]

Thank You

Comment: Hard to say unless you explain the steps you took.

Comment: I created new ootb custom list. I added couple of columns  but when I went to add create new column and selected look up  that gave me that error